# Dynamically adding new text box after button press is not working - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am creating an Edit Employee form and there is a button `Add new skill` which need to create new text box to add the skill.
[image: The sample output]

But when I click on `Add new skill`, it is not adding any new text boxes and displaying these details inside the console.

[image: Console]

My typescript code :

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, NgForm, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { EmployeeDepartment } from '../employee-department-class';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-emp-form-builder',
  templateUrl: './edit-emp-form-builder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-emp-form-builder.component.css']
})
export class EditEmpFormBuilderComponent implements OnInit {

  /**
   * Using some default values and may be different from other component
   */


  department = [
    new EmployeeDepartment(1, 'Payroll'),
    new EmployeeDepartment(2, 'Internal'),
    new EmployeeDepartment(3, 'HR')
  ]

  skills: any = []
  employeeDetails = this.fb.group({
    employeeName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(20)]],
    department: [null, [Validators.required]],
    skills: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.control('')
    ])
  });
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  get skill() {
    return this.employeeDetails.get('skills') as FormArray;
  }

  addSkill() {
    this.skills.push(this.fb.control(''));
  }

  onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    console.log(f);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

My HTML code for the skill

```html
 <div formArrayName="skills">
    <h3>Skill</h3>
    <button (click)="addSkill()">Add new skill</button>
    <div *ngFor="let s of skill.controls; let i = index">
      <label>Skill:
        <input type="text" [formControlName]="i">
      </label>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: follow this blog : https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/add-push-and-remove-form-fields-dynamically-to-formarray-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-acf61b4a2afe

Comment: you has a type error is `this.skill.push(this.fb.control(''));`, you wrote `skills` -ends in "s"- (the "this.skill is the "getter" you has)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the variable `skills: any = []` from your code.
Rename `get skill()` to `get skills()`